# PreOrder Traversal in Python Recursive mrethod

Tags: python, python-2.7

[Why is this struck in loop,Can you please help  me](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class+createTreeNode(%29%3A%0A++++def+__init__(self,value%29%3A%0A++++++++self.value%3Dvalue%0A++++++++self.left%3DNone%0A++++++++self.right%3DNone%0Adef+preOrderTraversal(root%29%3A%0A++++while(root%29%3A%0A++++++++print+root.value%0A++++++++preOrderTraversal(root.left%29%0A++++++++preOrderTraversal(root.right%29%0A++++%0A++++return%0Adef+insertNodetoBST(root,i%29%3A%0A++++if(root%3D%3DNone%29%3A%0A++++++++return+createTreeNode(i%29%0A++++temproot%3Droot%3B%0A++++while(temproot%29%3A%0A++++++++if(temproot.value%3Ei%29%3A%0A++++++++++++if(temproot.left%3D%3DNone%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++temproot.left%3DcreateTreeNode(i%29%0A++++++++++++++++return+root%0A++++++++++++temproot+%3D+temproot.left%0A++++++++else%3A%0A++++++++++++if+(temproot.right+%3D%3D+None%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++temproot.right+%3D+createTreeNode(i%29%0A++++++++++++++++return+root%0A++++++++++++temproot%3Dtemproot.right%0A++++return+root%0A%0A%0A%0Adef+createBSTfromList(%29%3A%0A++++root%3DNone%0A++++l+%3D+%5B1,2%5D%0A++++for+i+in+l%3A%0A++++++++root%3DinsertNodetoBST(root,i%29%3B%0A++++preOrderTraversal(root%29%3B%0A%0AcreateBSTfromList(%29%3B&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

```
class createTreeNode():

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
        self.left=None
        self.right=None


def preOrderTraversal(root):

    while(root):
        print root.value
        preOrderTraversal(root.left)
        preOrderTraversal(root.right)

    return
def insertNodetoBST(root,i):

    if(root==None):
        return createTreeNode(i)
    temproot=root;
    while(temproot):
        if(temproot.value>i):
            if(temproot.left==None):
                temproot.left=createTreeNode(i)
                return root
            temproot = temproot.left
        else:
            if (temproot.right == None):
                temproot.right = createTreeNode(i)
                return root
            temproot=temproot.right
    return root



def createBSTfromList():

    root=None
    l = [1,2]
    for i in l:
        root=insertNodetoBST(root,i);
    preOrderTraversal(root);

createBSTfromList();
```

Comment: Please include your code here, in the question. When I click on your link, my browser does some odd kind of redirect and gives me an editor window with no code in it, so there's no possible way for me to help you.

Comment: Thanks in Advance @Blckknght .Ive shared my Code

Comment: Why are you adding random "r"s in the middle of words (*mrethod*, *struck*)?

Answer (score 4):

Your code loops forever because you have `while(root)` in your `preOrderTraversal` function. Since you're not modifying `root` to anything falsey during the loop body, this will always run forever if `root` was not `None` to start with.

I think you want that line to be `if root` instead. This way you'll run the block either zero (base case) or one times (recursive case):

```
def preOrderTraversal(root):
    if root:
        print root.value
        preOrderTraversal(root.left)
        preOrderTraversal(root.right)
```

You don't need parentheses around the condition of an `if` or `while` statement. You also don't need any of the semicolons you're putting at the end of your lines. You may want to read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is a style-guide for Python code.

Comment: Thanks for solution,Understood my mistake